# jQuery on click function is not working for nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the clicked element's parent's attributes and the elements on which click event should fired are being added dynamically via jQuery. This is my code for click event which is not working at all

```
$("body").on('click', ".colors_storage input", function (event) {
    console.log($(event.target).parents().find('div.colors_storage_outer > select').attr('data-id'))
    /*console.log(parent.attr('data-id'))
    console.log(parent.attr('name'))*/
})
```

However, this code works but gives only one id 855 no matter which input elem is clicked.

```
$("body").on('click', $(".colors_storage input"), function (event) {
    console.log($(event.target).parents().find('div.colors_storage_outer > select').attr('data-id'))
    /*console.log(parent.attr('data-id'))
    console.log(parent.attr('name'))*/
})
```

and this is my html structure.

```
<div class="colors_storage_outer">
    <select data-id="855" name="colors[]" multiple="" class="form-control colors_storage bulk-colors select2-hidden-accessible" data-placeholder="Colors" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
    <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--above select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 121.25px;">
        <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
                <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                    <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                        <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Colors" style="width: 119.917px;">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="colors_storage_outer">
    <select data-id="853" name="colors[]" multiple="" class="form-control colors_storage bulk-colors select2-hidden-accessible" data-placeholder="Colors" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
    <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--above select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 121.25px;">
        <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
                <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                    <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                        <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Colors" style="width: 119.917px;">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have `.colors_storage input` anywhere in this code.

Comment: @MichaelCoker: The code does have `.colors_storage input`. Mind the space between the words. it is looking for the `input` element inside the element with `..colors_storage' class

Comment: @Sanchit where? The only `.colors_storage` element on the page is a `select` and an `input` can't be a child of a `select`

Comment: @MichaelCoker got that, but the second problem is still there. Should I update my question?

Comment: `$("body").on('click', $(".colors_storage input"),` makes no sense.

Comment: @MichaelCoker: The input is not a child of the `select`. There is a `</select>` at the end of the line. The `span` is a sibling of the `select`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette that's my point... the select is the only element with class `.colors_storage` and there is no `input` in the `select`s, so `.colors_storage input` doesn't exist on the page.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Sanchit is saying *"The code does have `.colors_storage input`"* - where? I don't see it.

Comment: @MichaelCoker: ok I get your point... You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector on your click handler doesn't match anything on the page. If you  just change it to `input`, the click handler fires, but it returns the wrong ID's. Seems to work if you change your code to use `$.closest()` and `$.find()` instead of `$.parent()`

```js
$("body").on('click', "input", function (event) {
    console.log($(this).closest('div.colors_storage_outer').find('> select').attr('data-id'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colors_storage_outer">
    <select data-id="855" name="colors[]" multiple="" class="form-control colors_storage bulk-colors select2-hidden-accessible" data-placeholder="Colors" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
    <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--above select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 121.25px;">
        <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
                <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                    <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                        <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Colors" style="width: 119.917px;">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="colors_storage_outer">
    <select data-id="853" name="colors[]" multiple="" class="form-control colors_storage bulk-colors select2-hidden-accessible" data-placeholder="Colors" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
    <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--above select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 121.25px;">
        <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
                <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                    <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                        <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Colors" style="width: 119.917px;">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please point out why my selector was giving wrong ids?

Comment: @Adamnick you're calling `$.parents()` which will select all parents, then using `$.find()` to find the selects - that returns all selects. It would work if you changed your line to this, so that it only finds the `.colors_storage_outer` parent of the `input` you clicked `console.log($(event.target).parents('div.colors_storage_outer').find('> select').attr('data-id'));`

Comment: @Adamnick but `$.closest()` is probably what you want to use instead, it won't return multiple items.

Answer (score 2):

There are some selectors that are wrong as other's have pointed out.

Also, I would use `closest('.colors_storage_outer')` with a selector so it goes up the tree and stops at the selector. You can do this with parents too (`parents('.colors_storage_outer')`). Then look for the select from there.

try:

```
$("body").on('click', "input.select2-search__field", function (event) {
    console.log($(this).closest('.colors_storage_outer').find('> select').attr('data-id'))
})
```

Comment: thank you, worked like a charm. can you please point out why my selector was giving wrong ids?

Comment: @Adamnick `$(event.target).parents().find('.colors_storage_outer > select')` will return 2 elements for your example. When you then call `.attr('data-id')` it returns the attribute value for the first element.